# mapStateToProps() in Redux app nesting state within state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I've hit a wall trying to figure out why the JSON data I'm fetching and storing on state isn't being mapped to my component props, yet appears when `console.log()`ed from within the `mapStateToProps()` function. Am I doing something wrong that I'm not seeing here?

**EDIT:** Apparently the properties on state are being mapped to the component but are nested. The `data` property, when logged from within `mapStateToProps()`, has to be accessed via `state.state.data`. Prior to this (see reducer), when `action.data` is logged, the data appears as expected. No strange nesting.
Perhaps something is wrong with the `connect` function?

See how there is a state property populated within the state object:

[image: See the data property populated within the state object]

Below is my component:

```
class ViewSelector extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchDataAsync('VIEW ALL');
  }

  selectView(event) {
    // this.props.data comes up undefined despite state being mapped
    // to the component props
    console.log('props: ' + this.props.data);
    this.props.filterData(event.target.innerHTML, this.props.data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <nav>
          <button onClick={this.selectView.bind(this)}>VIEW ALL</button>
          <button onClick={this.selectView.bind(this)}>VIEW LAST WEEK</button>
          <button onClick={this.selectView.bind(this)}>VIEW LAST MONTH</button>
        </nav>
        <Dashboard data={this.props.data}/>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state);
  // this console.log shows the state with the data property.
  return {
    data: state.data
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ViewSelector);
```

EDIT: Here is the reducer for clarification:

```
import {
  FETCH_DATA,
  FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_DATA_FAILURE,
  FILTER_DATA
} from '../actions/types';
import { getLastWeek, getLastMonth } from './reducer_helper';

const initialState = {
  error: '',
  loading: false,
  data: []
};

/* eslint-disable */
const app = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_DATA:
      return { ...state, error: '', loading: true };
    case FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      // console.log(action.data) returns data as expected.
      // no nesting...until it hits the mapStateToProps() function
      return { ...state, error: '', loading: false, data: action.data };
    case FETCH_DATA_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, error: action.error, loading: false };
    case FILTER_DATA:
      let data;
      if (action.view === 'VIEW LAST WEEK') {
        data = getLastWeek(state.data);
      } else if (action.view === 'VIEW LAST MONTH') {
        data = getLastMonth(state.data);
      } else {
        data = state.data;
      }
      return { ...state, error: '', loading: false, data };
  }
  return state;
}

export default app;
```

Action Creators for clarification on dispatches to Reducer:

```
export function fetchData() {
  return {
    type: FETCH_DATA
  };
}

export function fetchDataSuccess(data) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
    data: data
  };
}

export function fetchDataFailure(data) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_DATA_FAILURE,
    data
  };
}

export function filterData(view) {
  return {
    type: FILTER_DATA,
    view
  };
}

export function fetchDataAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchData());

    axios.get(DATA_URL)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(res.data));
    }).catch(err => {
      dispatch(fetchDataFailure(err));
    });
  };
}
```

How the entire app is being rendered & the Redux store:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Comment: mapStateToProps is supposed to get the complete state as an argument, what exactly are you asking ?

Comment: when I return `{ data: state.data }` the data array is present. But when I try to access that data within the component with `this.props.data` it comes up undefined. So it *looks* like somewhere along the road something is getting lost. Or I'm completely misinformed on what `mapStateToProps` is doing...

Comment: can you try logging in render and check once

Comment: @ThunderBird: looks like the same thing. `render: undefined`

Comment: so state.data  in mapStateToProps is not undefined but this.props.data in render is undefined, is that the case?

Comment: @ThunderBird: Correct. I'm stumped as to what might be causing that. It doesn't seem like there's any step in between `mapStateToProps` being called and the component props updating with what was on state.

Comment: Can you show how you are importing `ViewSelector`?

Comment: From your console log, it looks like you press the button before data is loaded.
And one more thing, try to call `state.state.data` in map function, looks like your state is invalid formatted. Provide us your reducer.

Comment: You get an error inside `<Dashboard data={this.props.data}/>` when it tries to access data.something, and it throws an error?

Comment: @DavinTryon: `import ViewSelector from './view_selector';`
@cema-sp: I think you're onto something. `state.state.data` logs the data the third time the state is changed (after FETCH_DATA, FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS). I included my reducer above.

Comment: `<Dashboard data={this.props.data}/>` probably doesn't have access to props.data at the time it's mounted, maybe put an if before showing it or passing prop to it. same goes for `selectView` too, put an if to check if props.data is available. or you can declare defaultProps too.

Comment: @PooyaSanooei: possibly true, but the real problem is that state is being nested as `state.state.data` or `this.props.state.data` for some reason.

Comment: How are you creating your store? It should just be:
`import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';`
`import app from 'reducers/app'; //exported reducer from your example`
`const store = createStore(app, mymiddleware);`

Comment: Hi @TomW, thanks for commenting. I've updated my question to include my Redux store wrapper and how it's all being rendered. It looks like I'm doing it slightly different, although I've never had a problem with this setup before. However, I'll try to import my reducer differently instead of `import reducer from './reducers/'`.

Comment: Have you got multiple reducers? Are you calling combineReducers? Your state would be shifted down if you are...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much reviewing, debugging and asking other devs, in a nutshell this is the problem I was facing: The reducer and how it was being imported into a main "manifest" file to manage all other reducers.

Basically, since I was only using **one reducer** in this project, there was no need for a manifest reducer file. See below:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import Reducer from './reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  state: Reducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

I don't know exactly why this was nesting state. Perhaps because, theoretically, we would be dealing with multiple reducers with different purposes (like a data reducer and a user reducer) and would need to nest those into our state tree to manage.

```
state = {
  // here is one nested reducer with its own properties
  data: {
    type: // somevalue,
    filtered: true
  },
  // here is another
  user: {
    name: // somename,
    password: // somepassword
  }
};
```

In short...be mindful of how your reducer is being imported into your `createStore` function and if it's the **only** reducer being used or if there's multiple reducers being run through a manifest file of sorts.

Cheers.

Comment: combineReducers nests the state of each reducer under the key used (so under state, for Reducer, in your code above). In your case, you shouldn't call combineReducers, since you only have one reducer. In a non-trivial app, you will likely have lots of reducers, each one under a descriptive key (e.g. not called 'state', but called after things in your domain).

Answer (score 5):

So your `mapStateToProps` value of `data` is returning an object. You probably want this instead:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state);
  // this console.log shows the state with the data property.
   return {
     ...state.app
   };
 }
```

This will give you access to the fields in your `data` reducer. Also, it's not clear from the example exactly how you will use the data, or what fields are included in it. Also, to start with, your reducer is not initialized to null or empty values for the fields it will use, which can definitely cause errors. Probably better to start with an `initialState` object:

```
const initialState = {
  error: '',
  loading: false,
  data: []
};

const app = (state=initialState, action) => {
 /* .... */
```

Comment: You're right. You've got half the answer from what it looks like. What I just noticed from @cema-sp pointing it out is that, for some reason, there is a state object nested inside another state object. So everything is appearing as `state.state.data` or `state.state.error` instead of just `state.data`. It's something wrong with my reducer but I'm unsure what.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue with `mapStateToProps`, where on the first render it would nest the initial state in an object with the key of state. When I updated the state using a dispatch method it would create another key-value pair. (The below entry in the console is when I console log state inside the mapStateToProps function).

Initial State which is nested:
[image: initial State which is nested]

I released that in my reducer function, I was returning state for my default case.

```
const initialState = {
    stateprop1: false,
    user_text: "empty",
    };

    const reducer1 = (state = initialState, action)             => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTION_TYPES.SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                stateprop1: true,
            };
        case ACTION_TYPES.FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                stateprop1: false,
            };
        case ACTION_TYPES.USER_INPUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                user_text: action.payload,
            };
        default:
            return {
                state,
            };
    }
};
```

​If, instead, I spread the state in the default case, the nesting behaviour wasn't observed.

```
default:
    return {
        ...state,
    };
```

So now if I console log state in the `mapStateToProps` function I get

State that isn't nested :
[image: state that isn't nested]

I hope this helps.