# Redux creates state with double nesting

Tags: redux, state

I have a redux app that, amongst other things, updates a single string, hence the state could be reflected as:

```
{
  theDataString: "someString",
  otherData: { ...some other data... },
  someListItems: [  ...a data array... ]
}
```

Hence I have the following reducer:

```
function updateDataString(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_DATA_STRING:
      return Object.assign({}, ...state, {theDataString: action.theDataString});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

However, when dispatch the `UPDATE_DATA_STRING` action, the `theDataString` value in the state becomes double nested:

```
{
  theDataString: {theDataString: "someString"},
  otherData: {... some other data... },
  someListItems: [ ... a data array ... ]
}
```

This same problem has already been encountered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695768/mapstatetoprops-in-redux-app-nesting-state-within-state). However, the solution for them was that they were calling `combineReducers` on a single reducer when that was unnecessary. In my case, I'm calling `combineReducers` on multiple reducers - so their answer doesn't work for me. Also note that the same nesting problem does not occur for other data, only the top-level string gets double nested.

What is going wrong here?

EDIT:
I'm connecting the component that updates `theDataString` like this:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {updateDataString} from './actions/actions';
import SomeList from './components/someList';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {someListItems: state.someListItems}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, placeHolder) => {
  return {
    updateDataString: (aString) => dispatch(updateDataSting(aString))
  }
};


export default SomeListConnected = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeList)
```

The action is set up as follows:

```
export const UPDATE_DATA_STRING = 'UPDATE_DATA_STRING';

export function updateDataString(aString) {
  return {type: UPDATE_DATA_STRING, theDataString: aString}
}
```

EDIT2: Changing the way the reducer updates the state is a natural place to look for answers. However I have tried various permutations here with little effect:

```
Object.assign({}, ...state, {theDataString: action.theDataString});
Object.assign({}, state, {theDataString: action.theDataString});
{...state, {theDataString: action.theDataString}};
```

None of the above fix the problem.

Comment: How are you connecting your component to Redux?

Comment: BTW Your action don't have `newString` as payload. It's like `return {type: UPDATE_DATA_STRING, theDataString: aString}`.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja, thanks, fixed. (The original code does not contain this error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've used `combineReducers`, your `updateDataString` reducer should be treating the state as a string, not an object:

```
function updateDataString(state = "", action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case UPDATE_DATA_STRING: return action.newString;
        default; return state;
    }
}
```

The slice reducer will only see the string value as its "state", so you need to treat it that way.

See [Using combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) for some further information on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return { ...state, theDataString: action.newString};
```

instead of this

```
return Object.assign({}, ...state, {theDataString: action.newString});
```

in your reducer.

I think you are using `...` spread operator in the wrong way. And no need to use `Object.assign()` here.

Read more about spread operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately, the suggested replacement did not solve the problem.

Comment: Yep. The state still comes out with `theDataString` double nested.

Comment: In your updated question with 3 attempts. Third attempt is different from my answer. Once recheck that.